# how to update hyperlink text in pdf using itextsharp in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink

my requirement is need to update hyperlink and hyperlink text in pdf using Itextsharp in c#.net application.I have gone through following link.

[Reading hyperlinks from pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959076/reading-hyperlinks-from-pdf-file)

By following this code i was succeeded to change hyperlink in PDF. but how to change hyperlink text

for example :
hyperlink is : http://www.google.com
hyperlink text is : ClickHere

I want change "ClickHere" to "SearchHere"

Any help,Appreciated

Comment: The hyperlink text is part of the normal page content. Changing it can be quite a challenge.

Comment: Looks like a link annotation over some text, like mkl said underlying text is most likely a part of page's content. It could be simpler to create a new element instead of this one, but it would look bad if text needs to reflow. I did things similar to this using other lib but have no experience in achieving such effect with iText.

Comment: Hi Team,If this task is done with other than ITextSharp in c#.net ,Please share your idea. we can implement it.