# Find Page number from PdfDestination in Pdf with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I know how to extract all marks I have added in my PdfDocument.
For that, I parse the document dictionnary:

```
for( int i=0; i < reader.XrefSize; i++) {           
  var obj = reader.GetPdfObject(i);
  if (obj != null && obj.GetType() == typeof(PdfDictionary) ) {
    PdfDictionary objDic = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary) obj;
```

Now I can locate `PdfName.DEST` fields in these PdfDictionary:

```
if (objDic.Keys.Contains(PdfName.DEST) == true) {                       
  var next = objDic.Get(PdfName.DEST);
    if (next.GetType() == typeof(PdfArray)) {
```

But, how to convert this `next` in `PdfDestination` ?
And how to get the 'vertical position', and better the 'page number' in the document ?

Best regards.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but [here's a much bigger example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10321886/231316) of resolving destinations.

Comment: The question is indeed incomplete. No distinction is made between *explicit destinations* (in which you get an indirect reference to a page dictionary) and *named destinations* (in which you get a name that refers to a page that is reference in a name tree containing references to pages).

Comment: I use PdfXChange Viewer for adding markers in Pdf file. I don't know if they are "named destination" or not. There is a text linked to. And ' reader.GetNamedDestinationFromStrings()' and 'reader.GetNamedDestinationFromNames()' return empty collections.