# convert html link to pdf in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

i have html file. which i want to convert into PDf with anchor tag.

while i am converting to PDF that time below error occurred.

**"Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'."**

anyone has idea how to convert html source with hyperlink to PDF? in page i have internal link like href="#table1".

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578316/editing-hyperlink-and-anchors-in-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: hi Rahul, thanks for your replay but i have to write link in PDF file. and that link is internal like "#table1". in short i have to create index page.