# How to get All link types with destinations in the pdf?

Tags: c#, itext

Stuck in one of our approach.
 We want to read the links in the pdf and change zoom property of each link.
 Able to get the links but unable to access the properties or change the property.
 How to get the destinations linked to particular link.?
 Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See the second method in my answer here for walking links and reading their properties (VB but you should be able to convert to C# easily). You should also have a copy of the PDF spec out, specifically section 8.4. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6599734/231316

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried the same and able to browse through the links but not able to get the string associated with the link. Uri link i am getting but not destination names associated with the link.

Comment: The text you see on a page is part of the content stream. Links are annotations and as such not related to the content stream. Annotations are added on top of the content stream at a position defined by a rectangle. There is no relationship between that rectangle and the content in the content stream that is present at that position. In short: your question reveals a lack of understanding regarding the PDF specification that can't be resolved in the number of characters available in a comment box.

Comment: Thanks a lot for details. I tried and read the PDF specification on link and using Itext library able to get the destination related to link.